# How can I have content in a html table cell centered when there is some other content float right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have content that is centered and content that is float right and I just realized that the centered text is shifted over to the left due to the float:right content.

The center text is using this css:

```
 .tableCell {
      text-align: center;
 }

 .floatRight img
 {
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

and here is the HTML:

```
   <td class="tableCell" id="697">
      <span class="floatRight">
           <img src="/arrow.png">
      </span>
      <b>1006</b><hr>Some Text<br>Some other text
   </td>
```

Is there anyway to have content inside a table cell that is centered and the horizontal location is not affected by float:right text?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comments, please review when you have a chance, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing it is to use absolute positioning on the arrow icon/image instead
of float, as shown below.

The vertical placement of the arrow may take some tweaking, depends on what the rest
of the design looks like.

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.tableCell {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.tableCell:hover > .floatRight 
{
    opacity:1;
}

.floatRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <span class="floatRight">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
      </span>
      <b>1006</b>
      <hr>Some Text
      <br>Some other text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks Marc - this worked but created another issue.  my current css shows the image only when you hover over the table cell.  When i made the change you suggested, the image no longer shows up when you hover over the cell.  i updated the css to highlight the issue.. do you have any suggestiosn?

Comment: Hi Leora: the issue is quite simple, you need to change the opacity on the correct element, `.floatRight` instead of `img` because `img` is a child of `.floatRight`, works nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

## [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jihudabekavi/1/edit)

Pay more attention **HTML**, maybe it's about typo.

```
<td class="tableCell id="697">
```

**Should be**

```
<td class="tableCell" id="697">
```